# How to replace new data for <tbody>?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to replace  in html table.any one help me
Please check my code below

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeRows()
    {
      var htmlString="<tr><td>bhanu</td><td>s</td></tr>";
      $("#myTable tbody").html(htmlString);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id='myTable'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>hari</td>
                <td>y</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onClick='changeRows()'>changText</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I got myTable `tbody` has no method  for html

Comment: `onClcik` and `fucntion` aren't going to do you any favors.

Comment: `onClck='changeRows()'` missing `()`  you have more syntax error and misspellings.  Correct and come back with clear question

Comment: `onClcik='changeRows'` is wrongly typed and you also don't have jQuery  library loaded.

Comment: check whether you have included jQuery plugin... and onclick event pass the function as like this **changeRows()** and change "fucntion" to "function".

Answer (score 1):

**replace**

```
 onClcik='changeRows'>
```

**with**

```
onClick='changeRows();'>
```

**change** `fucntion` **with** `function`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeRows()
{
    var htmlString = "<tr><td>bhanu</td><td>s</td></tr>";
    $("#myTable tbody").html(htmlString);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not working like this also

Comment: and change `fucntion` to `function` too...

Comment: @user2862489 yes it will not work because you are also not adding jQuery lib and using jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 fucntion changeRows()
```

To:

```
  function changeRows()
```

And change:

```
<button onClcik='changeRows'>changText</button>
```

To:

```
<button onclick='changeRows()'>changText</button>
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake I changed this but not working

Answer (score 0):

First of all Put here proper code.......
You can replace your code with below one....

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     function changeRows(){
      var htmlString="<tr><td>bhanu</td><td>s</td></tr>";
        $("#myTable tbody").html(htmlString);
     }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table id='myTable'>
 <thead>
  <th>
  <td>FirstName</td> 

 <td>LastName</td>
</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>hari</td><td>y</td></tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

  <button onclick="changeRows()" >changText</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: alya mandip tu...????

Comment: @DipeshParmar, ha ... :-)  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38959/room-for-m-and-d

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this: [**Fiddle for this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qeJb/)

#### html:

```
  <table id='myTable'>
<thead>
    <th>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
    </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>hari</td>
        <td>y</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button onClick='changeRows()'>changText</button>
```

Then in the head section add this library:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<script>
    function changeRows() {
  //-^^^^^^^----------------------spell it correctly too
        var htmlString = "<tr><td>bhanu</td><td>s</td></tr>";
        $("#myTable tbody").html(htmlString);
    }
</script>
```

and see this :

```
onClick='changeRows()'
^^^^^^^-------------------spell it correctly
```